# Tile small image size guidelines?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

Having read some of the guidelines for images, I am still unsure of the required sizes for the small image on tiles, such as in TileWideSmallImageAndText01

References:

[Tile and toast image sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781198.aspx),
[Guidelines for scaling to pixel density](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx),
[The tile template catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only requirement is:-

> Tile images must have dimensions less than or equal to 1024x1024 pixels, have a file size of less than or equal to 200 KB, and be of type .png, .jpg, .jpeg, or .gif. There are no bit-depth or color requirements for an image as long as it meets the other requirements.

The system will handle scaling correctly for you. 200kb is the hardest as you will almost certainly have to resize your images. If you don't get it right the tile just won't be displayed.

Comment: I have a 40x40 image that is being scaled up when using it with TileWideSmallImageAndText01 and looks pixelated. What size(s) should I use so that the small image doesn't get scaled? I haven't been able to find that information.

Comment: I use 300*168 and that doesn't look pixalated to me. The file size works out at 20.8kb.

Answer (score 1):

Fall into the pit of success by using the Package designer available in VS2012.  Double-click the Package.appxmanifest item in the Solution Explorer window to open the designer.  It shows you exactly what image sizes you need.  Do note that you should supply multiple sizes that work with different DPI settings on the user's machine.  You only need to supply one for the 100 scale but then your image will be rescaled and is likely to show some pixelation artifacts.

Documenting what you see in the designer, ordered by scale (80, 100, 140, 180):

- Logo: 120x120, 150x150, 210x210, 270x270
- Wide logo: 248x120, 310x150, 434x210, 558x270
- Small logo: 24x24, 30x30, 42x42, 54x64
- Store logo: missing, 50x50, 70x70, 90x90

Answer (score 1):

Tile sizes are as follows:
Wide Tile: 310x150
Small Square: 150x150
Large Square: 310x310

[choosing_between_different_tile_sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh465403.aspx#choosing_between_different_tile_sizes)